# Visual Studio BeforeBuild using xcopy command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build-process, xcopy

I am using the following beforebuild target and this works fine:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" $(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec Command="xcopy ..\mycomponent\mylateboundassembly\bin\debug\*.* bin /q /r /y">
  </Target>
```

however when the folder mycomponent has a space in it (my component) which i cannot remove(legacy code), I cannot get xcopy to work

Anyone know a way use xcopy in beforebuild where paths have a space?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by performing the following:
Add  an item to the property group (test)

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        .....
    <Test>"..\x space\ClassLibrary2"</Test>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then in Exec command use the property group item

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" $(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec Command="xcopy $(Test)\bin\Debug\*.* bin /q /r /y">
    </Exec>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the file path.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition=" $(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec Command="xcopy \"..\mycomponent\mylateboundassembly\bin\debug\*.*\" bin /q /r /y">
</Target>
```

Comment: sorry was not finished. So i then tried Command="xcopy '..\mycomponent\mylateboundassembly\bin\debug*.*' bin /q /r /y"> but am now getting Error 1 The command xcopy exited with code 4.